# javascript nodelist associate click

Tags: javascript, dom, native-code, nodelist

I'm willing to learn to manipulate the DOM with JS this holiday
I'm starting with simple things, like:

```
var sliderControler = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-controler");
var slideAtual = 0;

for(i = 0; i < sliderControler.length;i++) {
  sliderControler[i].click(function(){
    console.log("I love to screw my brain with js");
  })
}
```

Why I cannot associate this event?
I have a node list right?

document.getElementsByClassName then, returns a nodeList,
and jQuery $(".slider-controler") returns a object.

what is the difference between the object returned from jQuery the nodelist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you're firing a click event for each of the `HTMLElement`s in the`NodeList`(`sliderControler`).

Each of the elements of the `NodeList` is an `HTMLElement`. To bind a click handler to the elements in the NodeList use `addEventListener` or assign the handler to the `onclick` property.

```
for(i = 0; i < sliderControler.length;i++) {
  sliderControler[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("I love js");
  });
}
```

If you're using jQuery, you don't need to use a loop to bind a click handler.

```
$('.sliderControler').click(function() {
    console.log("I love js");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the click event for an Element with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
sliderControler[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("I love to mess my brain with js");
});
```

With jQuery you could just do the following to handle the click event for all elements with class `.slider-controler`

```
$('.slider-controler').on('click', function () {
    console.log("I love to mess my brain with js");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from jQuery is not a true NodeList, but instead is a special jQuery object. The jQuery click() method accepts a function as an event handler like you have in your code above, howver the native Element object does not.

try Changing sliderController.click(function...
To sliderController.onclick = function...

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by the jQuery selector is a jQuery-wrapped collection of elements. The methods you have directly available on DOM elements are quite different.

I would suggest, as a start, the MDN documentation on the `Element` interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element

For binding events, you typically have two options:

1. Use the corresponding `on*` attribute:

   ```
   sliderController[i].onclick = function() {
     /* ... */
   }
   ```

   That is typically discouraged though, as it makes you unable to bind more than one handler to a given event.
2. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

   ```
   sliderController[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     /* ... */
   });
   ```

You might want to check out some [notes on MDN about addEventListener vs on*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Notes)